# Let $A$ be a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Then $A$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, is the converse true?

Tags: general-topology

[image]

Question: Is the converse true? My claim is yes it is true. Below is how I showed that.

[image]

[image]

I think this looks good to me but I am not sure. Hence, it would be great if someone verifies my proof. Let me know if it needs a fix, better notation and style. Appreciate your help & support.

Comment: yeah $x = n$, but I guess I didn't use separate variables for finite sub-cover. wat should I do?

Comment: Your last sentence asserts that $A^c$ is an interval, which is wrong.

Comment: No, it does not look good.  There is glare on portions of it and general it is so tedious to read these hand scribbled photo questions, that I and others do not bother to read them.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Can u pls tell me how to fix it?